# Debugger does not hit any breakpoints

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, debugging, breakpoints

I tried using debug mode on vs code, but when I set a breakpoint and debug, it doesn't hit any points, just executes the program and writes down the outputs.

My `launch.json` configurations

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [
                //"${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.inp"//the input file's directory
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
            
        }
    ]
}
```

The task.json

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\MinGW64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

settings.json

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "iostream": "cpp",
        "numeric": "cpp",
        "ostream": "cpp",
        "iomanip": "cpp",
        "*.tcc": "cpp",
        "valarray": "cpp",
        "sstream": "cpp",
        "regex": "cpp",
        "map": "cpp",
        "limits": "cpp"
    }
}
```

An example of my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#define FOR(n) for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
#define lim (long long int)(10E9 + 7)


void IO(std::string filename){
    freopen((std::string{filename} + ".inp").c_str(), "r", stdin);
    freopen((std::string{filename} + ".out").c_str(), "w", stdout);
    return ;
}

struct properties{
    int x;
    int y;
} pos[1000001];
unsigned long long int res = 0, remain = 1, dup = 1;
long long int inputNumber;

int main(){
    //IO("CHICK");
    std::cin>>inputNumber;
    FOR(inputNumber){
        std::cin>>pos[i].x>>pos[i].y;
    }
    std::sort(pos + 1, pos + 1 + inputNumber, [](struct properties &a, struct properties &b){
        return a.y < b.y;
    });
    pos[inputNumber + 1].x = 1000000000;
    pos[inputNumber + 1].y = 1000000000;
    FOR(inputNumber){
        if(pos[i].y == pos[i + 1].y){
            ++dup;
        }
        else{
            res += dup * (dup - 1) / 2;
            dup = 1;
        }
    }
    dup = 1;
    std::sort(pos + 1, pos + 1 + inputNumber, [](struct properties &a, struct properties &b){
        if(a.x == b.x){
            return a.y < b.y;
        }
        return a.x < b.x;
    });
    FOR(inputNumber){
        if(pos[i].x == pos[i + 1].x){
            ++dup;
            if(pos[i].y == pos[i + 1].y){
                ++remain;
            }
            else{
                res -= remain * (remain - 1) / 2;
                remain = 1;
            }
        }
        else{
            res += dup * (dup - 1) / 2;
            res -= remain * (remain - 1) / 2;
            dup = 1;
            remain = 1;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<res;
}
```

I have searched the internet for this problem, but I can not find any solution, also tried to use external console, stopAtEntry, take inputs from both file and manually typing them. Nothing changes

Comment: "`#define FOR(n) for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
#define lim (long long int)(10E9 + 7)`" - You should stop listening to whomever taught you that that's a good idea.